# How to message/work queues work and what's the justification for a dedicated/hosted queue service

Tags: queue, message-queue

I'm getting into utilising work queues for my app and can easily understand their benefit: computationally or time-intensive tasks (like sending an email) can be put in a queue and run asynchronously to the request that initiated the task so that it can get on with responding to the user.

For example in my Laravel app I am using redis queueing. I push a job into onto the queue and a separate artisan process which is running on the server (`artisan queue:listen`) is listening on the queue for new jobs for it to execute.

My confusion is when it comes to the actually queuing system. Surely the queue worker is just a list of jobs with any pertinent data serialised and passed through. The job itself is still computed by the application.

So this leads me to wonder about the benefit and cost of large-scale queue workers like Iron.io or Amazon SQS. These services cost a fair amount for what seems like a fairly straightforward and computationally minimal task. Even with thousands of jobs a minute a simple redis or beanstalkd queue on the same server will surely be handled far easier than the actual jobs themselves. Having a hosted system seems like it'll slow down the process more due to the latency between servers.

Can anyone explain the workings of a work queue and how these hosted services improve the performance of such an application. I imagine the benefit is only felt once an app has scaled sufficiently but more insight would be helpful.

Comment: Here is a nice comparison of SQS vs IronMQ vs Beanstalkd: http://www.sitepoint.com/message-queues-comparing-beanstalkd-ironmq-amazon-sqs/